# EdtiText: Invisible number and how to make link to google map

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a very simple layout made of TextViews and disabled EditTexts put by turns. Most of the EditTexts contain plain text but I have two special fields and I have problem with them:

1. Phone number: as an autoLink type I set "phone". The problem is that a phone number is invisible until I click inside the edit:

   ```
            <EditText
               android:id="@+id/service_order_contact_phone"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_gravity="right"
               android:focusable="false"
               android:enabled="false"
               android:inputType="phone"
               android:gravity="right"
               android:autoLink="phone" >
            </EditText>
   ```
2. I would like to enable user to click address to open google map. I set an autoLink attribute to "map" but it seems not to work. Do you know how to do it?

   ```
            <EditText
               android:id="@+id/service_order_address"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_gravity="right"
               android:enabled="false"
               android:focusable="false"
               android:singleLine="false"
               android:lines="2"
               android:inputType="textPostalAddress|textMultiLine"
               android:autoLink="map"
               android:gravity="right" >
            </EditText>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think EditText and autoLink are designed to work together... Think about this scenario when the user is editing a value:

1. The user enters a phone number, say: 5557891234
2. The user made a mistake and clicks in the middle of the EditText to be able to change a digit in the middle of the phone number...
3. Instead of being allowed to edit the number, the link action takes them to the dialer with the incorrect phone number.

Comment: Yes, I know. But please notice that those EditTexts are disabled and non-focusable. I used the EditText because of its style - I wanted to distinct between labels (for that I used TextView) from values (for that I used disabled and non-fucusable EditText).

Comment: Then why not just use styles and style your value TextFields to look the way you want?